# Can I deploy a server to Heroku without a client?

Tags: heroku

I have built a backend server application without a frontend to it. Can I still deploy it to heroku ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Heroku only hosts apps.
As long as your backend server application listens on a specified port, and is able to receive and respond to HTTP requests, you can host it on Heroku.